# Two's complement binary multiplication

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I'm confused about where I'm going wrong in the following problem using binary multiplication with two's complement.

I am trying to multiply `12 * -6`.

We know that `12 = 01100` and `-6 = 11010`, and sign-extended we get `00000 01100 * 11111 11010`.  I tried multiplying these two numbers as follows:

```
     1111111010
   x 0000001100
   ------------
     0000000000
    0000000000
   1111111010
+ 1111111010
---------------
 10111110111000
```

This is definitely not `-72`, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You gotta keep extending the sign.

Comment: Ie, you should end up with 11111110111000

Comment: So there is sign extension that takes place on the product even after the multiplicand and multiplier were sign extended?

Comment: @user2485710 This is 2's complement, not sign magnitude.

Comment: Technically, you should end up with a result that is twice as long as the incoming operands (though I'm thinking that one bit of significance isn't used).  (I haven't thought much about this stuff since 1974, when I did the multiply/divide algorithms for an RCA/NASA computer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the digits from the left that don't fit in the data type:

```
10111110111000
```

truncates to

```
1110111000
```

You'll find that this is indeed `-72`.